# How should I incorporate a hotfix back into a feature branch using gitflow?

Tags: git, gitflow

I've started using [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a project, and I have an outstanding feature branch as well as a newly created hotfix. Per the gitflow workflow, the hotfix gets applied to both the *master* and *develop* branches, but nothing is said or done about extant feature branches.

Nevertheless, I'd like to incorporate the hotfix changes back into my feature branch, which as near as I can tell leaves three options:

1. Don't incorporate the changes. If the changes were needed for the feature branch, it should've been part of the feature branch.
2. Merge *develop* back into the feature branch. This seems to follow the gitflow workflow the best, but would cause out-of-order commits.
3. Rebase the feature branch onto *develop*. This would preserve commit order but rebasing seems to be completely absent from the general gitflow workflow.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: Feature branches are generally supposed to be very short-lived, it's kind of an SCM smell to be merging changes *into* them; is it impossible to just finish (or stabilize) the feature branch and merge it back?

Comment: @Aaronaught well the feature's not done/may go nowhere.  The basic situation is that a feature that's taking a couple of days to develop uncovered a bug that could potentially affect production data. Tests were written, hotfix applied to master/production, but the unfinished feature is still broken by the bug. Are you suggesting merging a half-completed feature into the development mainline? What happens if the feature doesn't pan out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with rebasing your feature branch onto *develop* to pick up the latest hot fixes.  Actually, frequently rebasing your feature branch against *develop* can be helpful, since it lets you keep your branch "up to date," which makes merging much easier when you get to that stage.

Comment: Yeah: looking around some more, circumstantial evidence—including the [gitflow 0.2 announcement](http://nvie.com/posts/an-upgrade-of-gitflow/) which added feature rebasing—is pointing to the regular git rebase workflow being the gitflow workflow as well.

Comment: Interesting.  I can't say I'm an expert on Gitflow, but my understanding was hotfix's were singular commits against master, not branches, and I simply cherry picked them to develop.  Reading up thought I was totally wrong on that.